# Selenium + Python: CSS Selector -- NoSuchElement error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a code which uses Selenium.
To test out a the `find_element_by_css_selector` function I wrote the following code:

```
self.browserProfile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
self.browserProfile.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('Chrome_Driver/chromedriver', chrome_options=self.browserProfile)
self.email = email
self.password = password
self.browser.get('http://samplePage.html')
inputs = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
print(inputs)
```

But I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)
```

How do I solve this error? 
The `chromedriver` and all required dependencies are fulfilled
I am running python 3.6.

Comment: Can you show the page?

Comment: seems locator is wrong, share page's source code for this element.

Comment: Share your HTML, please.

Comment: That button probably gets added late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button"}
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate the desired *WebElement* through the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have used.

The relevant HTML would have helped us to analyze your issue in a better way. However your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.25*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.25*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v53-55**

- You are using *chrome=70.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.45*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v70-72**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *unknown* to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.25* and the *Chrome Browser v70.0*

### Solution

- Keep *Selenium* upgraded to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: I'm not really sure why someone downvoted you. You explained the problem and multiple aspects of a solution for OP to solve it himself.

Comment: This solution worked. I updated the chromedriver to the latest version and it works smoothly now, thank you sir

Comment: Great news !!! I was sure about the actual problem of _version incompatibility_ where as @NoSplitSherlock 's support gave us the confidence that we were walking in the right direction to address your issue.